# What can be threshold for Model Overfitting?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I am running a logistic model via glm package.  I have got AUC for train data 97.8 and for test data 93.9. Can we call it as overfitting? lets suppose someone is getting AUC 94 for train data and 92 AUC on test data. cant we give some buffer for overfitting or does it need to be followed exactly like they have said in book? Please suggest.

Comment: Why would be overfitting with such good results in test data? I mean, do you expect the same AUC in both sets?

Comment: test set will likely be from a (slightly) different distribution or just instances that are harder to classify. Therefore models almost always tend to perform better on the train set. With that in mind, it depends on the problem at hand whether you can call 97.8 to 93.9 overfitting. Overfitting can also be seen as a relative measure: the second model you give is less overfitting to the training data.

Comment: @LaksanNathan Thank you for your reply. Can you help me understand which type of problem or where we can allow slightly overfitted models? just for my understanding as I am new to this field.

Comment: @javierazcoiti Yes to call it the model is good fit, AUC for test needs to equal or higher than train. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Goodness of fit in test data is usually lower than in train data. Your model could be considered to overfit if instead of 97.8 and 93.9 you could achieve, for example, 96 and 95, I think this is the idea of @LaksanNathan.

Comment: thanks. that answers my question.